# Are the elements of tuples, themselves tuples?

Tags: python

I'm slightly confused over tuple notation. Is each of the elements in a tuple treated as a tuple or as whatever type that element is?

For example, for the tuple `t = (1,2,3,4)`, `1 in t` is `True`, which means that the int `1` is in the tuple `t`.

However, if I evaluate `t[0:1]`, we get the **tuple** `(1,)`.

Even more confusing is the fact that `(1,) in t` is `False`.

What's going on here? Which is it; are the elements of `t` tuples or integers?

Comment: Clearly, `t[0:1]` does not return an element of `t`, but a "subtuple" of `t`, which is why `(1,) in t` is `False`.

Comment: You're accessing a one element wide slice of the tuple with `t[0;1]`.  Such slices are tuples, but the elements are still whatever type they were before.

Comment: An element of a tuple isn't a tuple, but a *slice* is. Try `t[0]` or `t[1]` to get an element rather than `t[0:1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not.

But slicing `[0:1]` will always give you a subset of the iterable. If you want to just get the element, just do so: `t[0]`. That is an integer, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The items inside a tuple can be tuples or other data types. You can even mix the types of items contained inside a tuple.

When you use `t[0:1]` you are slicing, and this gives you a segment of the object you are slicing. [read the docs](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html).

On the other hand you can access the item inside the tuple by indexing with the `t[0]`. [more docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

You can check the object types:

```
t = (1,2,3,4) 
type(t)
Out[12]: tuple

type(t[1])
Out[13]: int


type(t[:1])
Out[14]: tuple


t2 = ('a',1, (0,1)) 

for item in t2:
    print(type(item))

<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'tuple'>
```